# Using JQuery with .NET 1.1 web app

Tags: jquery

I have added jquery js file to a web page in .NET 1.1 web app.

And added this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("input").blur(function() {
            $(this).attr("background-color", "#000000");
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I tab off a textbox nothing happens.

This should work right in 1.1??

Malcolm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [css](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#namevalue) not attr:

```
 $(this).css("background-color", "#000000");
```